# Validating based on two different form data with WTF

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to take two different input job,income and validate both before submit. Like if job is "Office" income must be in range of (55000,13000) it has 3 more condition like this. I have tried to write custom validators but from documentation I understand you can only write per form field not combining two field and validate.

Answer (score 0):

for a custom validator, try using it similar to the standard EqualTo, which works with a different field.

```
class EqualTo:
    def __init__(self, fieldname, message=None):
        self.fieldname = fieldname
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        try:
            other = form[self.fieldname]
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise ValidationError(
                field.gettext("Invalid field name '%s'.") % self.fieldname
            ) from exc
        if field.data == other.data:
            return

        d = {
            "other_label": hasattr(other, "label")
            and other.label.text
            or self.fieldname,
            "other_name": self.fieldname,
        }
        message = self.message
        if message is None:
           message = field.gettext("Field must be equal to %(other_name)s.")

        raise ValidationError(message % d)
```